# nuxt-gmaps add bounds dynamically

Tags: google-maps, nuxt.js

Trying to get the map to read all locations that should be visible dynamically.

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: "GoogleMaps",
    props: {
      locations: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => {
          return [];
        },
      },
      visibleLocations: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => {
          return [];
        },
      },
      center: {
        center: Object,
      },
    },
    data() {
      return {
        userLocation: {},
        locationsVisibleOnMap: "",
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$refs.gMap.$mapCreated.then(() => {
        const B = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // locationsVisibleOnMap should be loaded here
        B.extend({
          lat: 33.972,
          lng: 35.4054,
        });

        this.$refs.gMap.fitBounds(B);
      });
    },
  };
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <GMap
      ref="gMap"
      :center="center"
      :options="{
            fullscreenControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
          }"
      :zoom="12"
    >
      <GMapMarker
        v-for="location in locations"
        :key="location.id"
        :position="{ lat: location.lat, lng: location.long }"
        @click="currentLocation = location"
      >
        <GMapInfoWindow :options="{ maxWidth: 200 }">
          <b>{{ location.name }}</b>
          <br />
          <br />
          <code>
            Lat: {{ location.lat }},
            <br />
            Lng: {{ location.long }}
          </code>
        </GMapInfoWindow>
      </GMapMarker>
    </GMap>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am continuously getting undefined references. There must be something I am doing fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently had to work with this using `nuxt-gmaps` and figured out how to do it, so adding this answer in case someone else stumbles upon this, first in your `template` have something like

```html
<GMap ref="gMap" @loaded="fitBoundsToMarkers">
```

and in your methods

```js
fitBoundsToMarkers(google) {
  const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); // creates a bounds object
  this.$refs.gMap.markers.forEach((marker) => bounds.extend(marker.getPosition())); // adds all the markers to the bounds object, you can filter it if you need that
  this.$refs.gMap.map.fitBounds(bounds, { left: 400 }); // fitBounds, you can also add padding, I have a left padding of 400px here
},
```

and that should allow you to fit bounds on load using the markers that you already set. if you need to fit bounds to some other points, you can add them to the bounds object using `extend`.

if you need to call `fitBoundsToMarkers` on your own from some other function, then you can get access to `google` from `this.$refs.gMap.google`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) like so

```js
async mounted() {
  await this.$nextTick();
  this.$refs.gMap.$mapCreated.then(() => {
    const B = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // locationsVisibleOnMap should be loaded here
    B.extend({
      lat: 33.972,
      lng: 35.4054,
    });

    this.$refs.gMap.fitBounds(B);
  });
}
```

or using the callback

```js
mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$refs.gMap.$mapCreated.then(() => {
      const B = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      // locationsVisibleOnMap should be loaded here
      B.extend({
        lat: 33.972,
        lng: 35.4054,
      });

      this.$refs.gMap.fitBounds(B);
    });
  });
}
```

gMaps takes a while to load, so for any operations on it you should always do so on the nextTick.
In some cases you might need to wait for the next tick again before calling fitBounds to get the correct bounds or if you wanted to change them later on for some other event.

Comment: According to https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/260#issuecomment-393533119 mapCreated was replaced with mapPromise.

Tried the above but I still get this.$refs.gMap.$mapPromise and this.$refs.gMap.$mapCreated undefined

Comment: @PotneySwitters are you using vue-google-maps or nuxt-gmaps ? they are both wrappers on google maps apis but I don't think they are related to each other. if your issue is that the $mapPromise is undefined that could be because it's not implemented in `nuxt-maps`

Comment: It is nuxt-maps :( Thanks. Trying the vue-google-maps now